# using a view for multiple controller Actions, return to initial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view which displays a list of items, I'm planning on using Actions with the View (the view is the same, just different data is displayed)

I'm using a dialog to do the addedit (this works fine) I will be using the same dialog throughout.

My query is best demonstrated in the below example...

Equipment View

ActionResult PCs()...
ACtionResult Laptops()...

so under the PCs controller I hit edit and modify the data, when I update the data, I'm returned back... I want to get returned back to the action I started with

so if I edit a pc, on update, the dialog returns me back to the pcs, if I edit a laptop I go back to laptops.

I was thinking I need to pass another variable through to the addeditview to show which controller referred me.

does the above make sense, can anyone offer the best way to achieve this?

EDIT: Adding current code

I can't think how do to it at the moment, I thought id set the mode under users, and retrieve the mode, in the addedit get, but am not sure how to send mode to the add edit get

can I do it in the below somewhere?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "AddEditRecord", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "editDialog" })
```

#####Controller

// GET: /Users

```
public ActionResult Users()
{

    ViewBag.Title = "User Equipment";
    ViewBag.Mode = "Users";
    string[] arrItems = new string[] { "Laptop", "Workstation", "Mobile","Monitor","Other Peripheral","Home Printer","Home Router","Removable Device" };

    var tblequipments = from d in db.tblEquipments.Include(t => t.User).Include(t => t.ChangeLog).AsEnumerable()
                        where (arrItems.Contains(d.AssetType)) &&  
                                (d.Deleted != 1 || d.Deleted == null) && 
                                (d.Stock != 1 || d.Stock == null) && 
                                (d.DecommissionDate == Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01") || d.DecommissionDate == Convert.ToDateTime("0001-01-01") || d.DecommissionDate == null) 
                        select d;
    return View("Equipment",tblequipments.ToList());
}

//GET: /AddEdit
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddEditRecord(int? id,string mode)
        {
            ViewBag.Mode = mode;
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                if (id != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.IsUpdate = true;
                    tblEquipment Equipment = db.tblEquipments.Where(m => m.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                    return PartialView("_AddEdit", Equipment);
                }

                ViewBag.IsUpdate = false;
                return PartialView("_AddEdit");
            }
            else
            {
                if (id != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.IsUpdate = true;
                    tblEquipment Equipment = db.tblEquipments.Where(m => m.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                    return PartialView("AddEdit", Equipment);
                }
                ViewBag.IsUpdate = false;
                return PartialView("AddEdit");
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddEditRecord(tblEquipment Equipment, string cmd)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                switch (cmd)
                {
                    case "Add":
                        try
                        {
                            db.tblEquipments.Add(Equipment);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                        }
                        catch { }
                        break;
                    case "Update":
                        try
                        {
                            tblEquipment Item = db.tblEquipments.Where(m => m.ID == Equipment.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (Item != null)
                            {
                                Item.AssetNo = Equipment.AssetNo;
                                Item.MachineName = Equipment.MachineName;
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                        }
                        catch { }
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_AddEdit", Equipment);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("AddEdit", Equipment);
            }
        }
```

##### ADD Edit Modal View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddEditRecord", "Equipment", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",OnSuccess = "onSuccess()", LoadingElementId = "dvLoading" }))
{    
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div id="equipmentDialog">    

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>
        @if (ViewBag.IsUpdate == true)
        {
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        }
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MachineName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MachineName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MachineName)
```

Comment: I don't like that strategy, but it's a personal choice. If you want to work that you, you must send to the view the name of the action that must receive the redirect. That view is posting to another action, right?

Comment: yeah so ActionPC > EquipmentView > EditEquipmentView > Update > go back to ActionPC, if that makes sense?

Comment: `EditEquipment` is posting to `Update`. When you do so, you must tell that action where to redirect the result to. Therefore, you must send it from your form, and that value comes from the original action (`PC`, in that case). Does that make sense for you?

Comment: yeah that makes sense, what's the best method of getting that action to the EditEquipmentView?

Comment: Could you add to your question code from the actions `PC` and `Update`?

Answer (score 0):

sorted!

1.I added a viewbag action
2.Used that viewbag in the querystring for edit
3.put the querystring in a hiddenfield
4.got the fieldvalue on form post and redirect to action of the field value

Thanks for the help